# Grails GORM 'or' not working with associations

Tags: grails, associations, grails-orm, h2

In the following example, I'd expect Product.searchAll to match both
additives and products, but it seems to ignore `eq('name', taste)`.

```
class Additive {
    String flavor
    static belongsTo = [product:Product]
}

class Product {
    String name
    static hasMany = [additives:Additive]

    static constraints = {
            name nullable:true
    }

    static namedQueries = {
        searchAll { taste ->
            or {
                eq('name', taste)
                additives { eq('flavor', taste) }
            }
        }
        searchAdditives { taste ->
            additives { eq('flavor', taste) }
        }
        searchProducts { taste ->
            eq('name', taste)
        }
    }
}

class SearchSpec extends grails.plugin.spock.IntegrationSpec {
    def choc, muff

    def 'searchAll should return products and additives that match - THIS FAILS'() {
        setup:
            createTestProducts()
        expect:
            Product.searchAll("chocolate").list() == [choc, muff]
    }


    def 'searchProducts should return only products that match - THIS PASSES'() {
        setup:
            createTestProducts()
        expect:
            Product.searchProducts("chocolate").list() == [choc]
    }

    def 'searchAdditives should return only additives that match - THIS PASSES'() {
        setup:
            createTestProducts()
        expect:
            Product.searchAdditives("chocolate").list() == [muff]
    }

    private def createTestProducts() {
        // create chocolate
        choc = new Product(name:'chocolate').save(failOnError:true, flush:true)
        // create a chocoloate-flavored muffin
        muff = new Product(name:'muffin').addToAdditives(flavor:'chocolate').save(failOnError:true, flush:true)
    }
}
```

The SQL generated is as follows:

```
select this_.id as id1_1_, this_.version as version1_1_,
this_.name as name1_1_, additives_1_.id as id0_0_,
additives_1_.version as version0_0_, additives_1_.flavor as
flavor0_0_, additives_1_.product_id as product4_0_0_ from product
this_ inner join additive additives_1_ on
this_.id=additives_1_.product_id where (this_.name=? or
(additives_1_.flavor=?))
```

Is there something wrong with my syntax, or is this a problem with Grails, GORM or H2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess, quickly looking at your query, is that Grails / GORM is performing an `inner join`.  An inner join only matches if a relationship exists between the tables.  In the example above, that query will *never* match `choc`, because `choc` does not have any associated additives.

So, it's not the `or` that's failing, it's the actual query.  Fire up **localhost:8080/{yourapp}/dbConsole** and run that same query, but without the `where` statement.  You should see that you only get products with one or more additives.

I believe (not tested) you can force a `LEFT JOIN` using syntax like this:

```
import org.hibernate.criterion.CriteriaSpecification
...

    searchAll { taste ->
        createAlias("additives", "adds", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
        or {
            eq('name', taste)
            eq('adds.flavor', taste)
        }
    }
```

This should force a left (or outer) join, allowing for products that do not have a matching additive.  Note: It's possible to get duplicate results when using outer joins, but this depends on your particular usage scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - will investigate!

Comment: Works straight out of the box - thanks for the help!  Do you think this is a bug in Grails 2?  Pretty sure this worked in 1.3.7 with HSQLDB.

Comment: If I recall, this was a known change in Grails or Hibernate.  It was made for performance reasons.  I'm not 100% in agreement, because it affects any relationship where you can have 0 related items. :-\