# What's the default fetch strategy for one-to-many in Grails 2.3?

Tags: grails, fetch

I recently migrated my app to Grails 2.3.6, i notice that the defaut strategy to fetch associations in a one-to-many relation has been changed.

I worked on Grails 1.3.x before, it used "select" strategy to fetch "many" side by default.
and now, it use a "inner join" to fetch "many" associations.

it's that right ?

Comment: Yes, and lazy, from Grails version 2.2.*, if I am not wrong.

Comment: Maybe this links will be helpfull for You #Greedydp:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10528731/grails-gorm-or-not-working-with-associations
http://grails.org/doc/2.0.3/ref/Database%20Mapping/fetch.html